# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on startAsynchronous request using ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, exc-bad-access

I am getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the Line:

`[asiUsernameRequest startAsynchronous]`;

in this code.  Spent hours trying to figure it out, but no solution.  Any idea?

```
    NSString *usernameValue = (NSString*)usernameField.text;
    NSLog(@"username selected: %@", usernameValue);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/api/usernameCheck"];
    //ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    asiUsernameRequest = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] retain];
    [asiUsernameRequest setPostValue:usernameValue forKey:@"username"];
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"usernameCheck", nil];
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"action", nil];
    asiUsernameRequest.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
    [asiUsernameRequest setDelegate:self];
    [asiUsernameRequest startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: You should also mention not commonly known 'ASIHTTPRequest' framework you are using: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: A possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430601/asihttp-addoperation-when-other-threads-are-running/2430734#2430734

Comment: What happens if you comment out every line between asiUsernameRequest = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:] and the [asiUsernameRequest startAsynchronous]? Does it still throw the error?

Comment: when i comment out  [asiUsernameRequest setPostValue:usernameValue forKey:@"username"]; it doesnt throw an error.  But that would eliminate the use of ASIFormDataRequest;

Answer (score 0):

Try retaining the `usernameField`'s `text`:

```
NSString * usernameValue = [[usernameField.text] retain];
```